# Mozilla Browser Compatibility UI issue

Tags: user-interface, browser, cross-browser, compatibility, mozilla

When i fix the issues for Mozilla compatibility they work fine on my system, but when i want to check those changes on a different PC using same version of Mozilla, I am getting some UI issues.

Same version of Mozilla are giving different height & widths of same div when checked on different computers.

Screen size is same, screen resolution is same and every thing is working fine when i use Chrome on both the PCs.

Please advice me if i am missing something here that might help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this inconsistencies in things like default line heights, widths margins and font sizes of headings is due to default behaviours of own browser. To resolved this you can use reset or normalize css to have consistent behaviour first. Then give your custom or required css on element.
Please find the links below:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/